# HTML - table how to use it to make a page

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to make something like this picture

[image]
Using Table and as little as possible of css can someone help me reach this result.

My current code is this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Mailing</title>  
        <meta name="author" content="Ronald Dewindt">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><img src="images/parksenz.jpg" alt="Parksenz"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Geachte klant,</p>
                    <p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Voor uw e-mail is een reset link aangevraagd voor het wijzigen van het e-mailadres bij Green-parking. Gebruik onderstaande link om het e-mailadres te bevestigen. U moet daarna met uw gewijzigde e-mailadres inloggen.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="1"><img src="images/@Logo.jpg" alt="@"></td>
                <td align="right" colspan="1"><img src="images/url.jpg" alt="background" ></td>
                <td colspan="1" style="background-color:#E4E5E7;">
                    <p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Klik hier om uw wachtwoord opnieuw in te stellen of kopieer en plak deze URL in de webbrowser: {$CallbackUrl} </p>
                </td> 
                 
                 
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Hartelijk dank dat u Greenparking gebruikt.</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Met vriendelijke groet,</p>
        <p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Het team van Greenparking</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td align="right" colspan="1" style="background-color:#E4E5E7;>"><img src="images/@.jpg"></td>
                    <td colspan="2"><p>support@greenparking.nl</p></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><img src="images/footerImage.jpg"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used to this css

```css
table{border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;}
td {
    border: 0;
}

table > tbody > tr:first-child td {
    background: gray;
    line-height: 53px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Mailing</title>  
        <meta name="author" content="Ronald Dewindt">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><img src="images/parksenz.jpg" alt="Parksenz"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Geachte klant,</p>
                    <p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Voor uw e-mail is een reset link aangevraagd voor het wijzigen van het e-mailadres bij Green-parking. Gebruik onderstaande link om het e-mailadres te bevestigen. U moet daarna met uw gewijzigde e-mailadres inloggen.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="1"><img src="images/@Logo.jpg" alt="@"></td>
                <td align="right" colspan="1"><img src="images/url.jpg" alt="background" ></td>
                <td colspan="1" style="background-color:#E4E5E7;">
                    <p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Klik hier om uw wachtwoord opnieuw in te stellen of kopieer en plak deze URL in de webbrowser: {$CallbackUrl} </p>
                </td> 
                 
                 
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Hartelijk dank dat u Greenparking gebruikt.</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Met vriendelijke groet,</p>
        <p style="color:rgb(110,110,110);">Het team van Greenparking</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td align="right" colspan="1" style="background-color:#E4E5E7;>"><img src="images/@.jpg"></td>
                    <td colspan="2"><p>support@greenparking.nl</p></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><img src="images/footerImage.jpg"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```